# Removing custom meta data

Tags: functions, custom-field, urls, forms

I wrote some code to add some custom meta boxes to my theme admin panel, and it works like a charm. The problem is I can't figure out how to make it so I can remove some of the data too.

Example:
I can upload multiple pictures in my acp and I would like that 'Remove' button actually works.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI6vO.jpg)

Here is my functions.php:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'bb_article_init' );
function bb_article_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Article', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Article', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Articles', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Article', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'article', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Article', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Article', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Article', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Article', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Articles', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Articles', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Articles:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No articles found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No articles found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'article' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-list-view',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type('article' ,$args );
}
register_taxonomy("Categories", array("article"), array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Categories", "singular_label" => "Category", "rewrite" => true));

add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
    add_meta_box("article-price-meta", "Price", "article_price", "article", "side", "high");
}
function article_price(){
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $price = $custom["article_price"][0];
    echo '<label>Price:</label>';
    echo '<input name="article_price" value="'. $price.'" />';
}

add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
function save_details(){
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "article_price", $_POST["article_price"]);
}

function add_custom_meta_boxes() {
    function bb_article_images() {
        wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'bb_article_images_nonce');

        $imgArray = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'bb_article_images', false); 
        foreach($imgArray as $img){
            $fileName = substr(strrchr($img['url'],"/"), 1);
            echo "<form action='functions.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='fileName' value='".$filename."'>";
            echo $fileName;
            echo "<button type='submit'>Remove</button>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<br><br>";
        }
        $html = '<p class="description">';
        $html .= 'Upload your images here.';
        $html .= '</p>';
        $html .= '<input type="file" id="bb_article_images" name="bb_article_images[]" value="" size="25" multiple />';
        echo $html;
    }
    add_meta_box(
        'bb_article_images',
        'Article images',
        'bb_article_images',
        'article',
        'side',
        'high'
    );

}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_boxes');

function save_custom_meta_data($id) {
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['bb_article_images_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
      return $id;
    } 

    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
      return $id;
    } 

    if('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
      if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
        return $id;
      } 
    } else {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $id)) {
            return $id;
        } 
    } 
    $files = array_filter($_FILES['bb_article_images']['name']);
    $total = count($files);

    $is_image = true;

    if($total > 0) {

        $supported_types = array('image/jpeg');

        for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
            $arr_file_type = wp_check_filetype(basename($_FILES['bb_article_images']['name'][$i]));
            $uploaded_type = $arr_file_type['type'];

            if(!in_array($uploaded_type, $supported_types)){
                $is_image = false;
                die("test");
            }
        }

        if($is_image) {
            for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){
                $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['bb_article_images']['name'][$i], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['bb_article_images']['tmp_name'][$i]));

                if(isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != 0) {
                    wp_die('There was an error uploading your file. The error is: ' . $upload['error']);
                } else {
                    add_post_meta($id, 'bb_article_images', $upload);
                }
            }
        } else {
            wp_die("The file type that you've uploaded is not an image.");
        }

    }

}

add_action('save_post', 'save_custom_meta_data');

function update_edit_form() {
    echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}
add_action('post_edit_form_tag', 'update_edit_form');
?>
```

Few things came to my mind but I failed to make any work. Like creating custom nonce? and when it gets triggered through URL do a MySQL query for removal, Make a forms (as is now) and trigger them through POST, calling another php file, calling the functions.php, using some wp builtin functions...

Can you at least point me out at how should this be done?

Thank you a lot! :D